# regex js parse string of functions

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I'm looking to create a regex expression that will parse a string of functions, typically looking like this:

```
"  a   b ( )     c  d ( 1, 2 )  text(' asdf  sg sf  sd sdf ')  "
```

into an array with all spaces removed except for spaces within either single or double quotes. IE, something like this:

```
['a','b()','c','d(1,2)',"text(' asdf sg sf sd sdf ')"]
```

I'm sure this type of problem has been around since the birth of computing so I am surprised that I can't find a neat regex solution to this problem already on the web!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: sorry, I left out the quotes in the array. I meant: ['a','b()','c','d(1,2)',"text(' asdf sg sf sd sdf ')"]

Comment: so edit the answer and correct it

Comment: what exactly makes `a` and `c` functions?

Comment: Please, for the sake of humanity tell me that you're not going to be `eval()`'ing these functions...

Comment: I am probably the world's worst regex programmer. I'm only capable of writing simple solutions like this : var s2 = s1.trim();  var s3 = s2.split(/[ ]+/);

Comment: I was able to come up with an expression to match the functions, but was not able to match just the letters, play around with it if you'd like and see what works for you: `/([A-z0-9_]*)(?: )?(?:\((.*)\))/gU`

Comment: Is eval safe if one does this: eval("this."+"f(a)") forcing all function to become methods encapsulated within a class?

Comment: Is the "function "     d(1,b()+x,text('asf'))     allowed?  Do you really mean *arbitrary expression*?  For what langauge?   Do you mean *arbitrary statement*?  Otherwise from your example it is just "identifier" "(",  list of string or number separated by commas, ")"

Answer (score 0):

Just say what you mean--a sequence of letters (`\w+`), maybe (`?`) followed by some white space (`\s*`) and something parenthesized (`\(.*?\)`:

```js
var str = "  a   b ( )     c  d ( 1, 2 )  text(' asdf  sg sf  sd sdf ')  ";

var re = /\w+(\s*\(.*?\))?/g;
//        ^^^                     IDENTIFIER
//               ^^^^^^^          ARGLIST

// Remove spaces in each result, except for spaces in "string literals" like 'a b'.
function squeeze(str) {
  return str.replace(/'.*?'| /g, match => match === ' ' ? '' : match);
}

console.log(str.match(re).map(squeeze));
```

This cannot handle nested function calls. That is probably close to impossible with regexp.